# Why is the GnuPG-sign checkbox disabled in SourceTree?

Tags: git, gnupg, atlassian-sourcetree

[image: Example screenshot]

Using Mac OS X Yosemite (10.10), I cannot active GnuPG-signing of commits in SourceTree, as the checkbox is disabled. How can I enable commit-signing?

Answer (score 56):

You likely aren't pointing the GPG Program setting (found in SourceTree -> Preferences -> Advanced) at the right bin. If you're using GPGTools on OS X, it should be `/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin`. [To navigate to the `/usr/bin` directory in the Open File dialog](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/118187/edit), click <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>g</kbd>

[image: SourceTree setting]

If you installed `gnupg` with Homebrew, [see @chakming`s answer in the comments below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26697343/why-is-the-gnupg-sign-checkbox-disabled-in-sourcetree/27069408#comment86720717_27069408).

Comment: To clarify, the ```GPG Program:``` should point to MacGPGs's bin directory and not the ```gpg``` binary itself

Comment: I installed gpg2 with homebrew and have it set in my git config (`git config --global gpg.program gpg2`). In SourceTree I have to specify `/usr/local/bin` in the GPG Program field.

Comment: for anyone using OSX and `brew install gnupg`, try to locate gng by `ls -la /usr/local/bin/gpg` and you will see the version:  `../Cellar/gnupg/2.2.6/bin/`, then open terminal and go `/usr/local/Cellar/gnupg/2.2.6/bin/`, then create a shortcut by `ln -s gpg gpg2`. Go to SourceTree -> Preferences and use `/usr/local/Cellar/gnupg/2.2.6/bin` as you GPG Program location then everything works fine

Comment: In SourceTree 2.7.1, this setting is in SourceTree > Preferences > Advanced tab.

Comment: I cannot add free text like the screen shot ... anyone else having that issues ? I use mojave OXS

Comment: @StackFlowed I updated the answer showing the correct procedure for the latest version.

Comment: The only this I'd add to @chakming 's answer, is that you can get the path to the gpg binary you are using with `which gpg`. Thanks!

Comment: Just wanted to say that @chakming's answer was the only way that solved this. Additionally, you don't need to create the shortcut in the versioned folder, you can create the link in the `usr/local/bin` directory:

`ln -s /usr/local/bin/gpg /usr/local/bin/gpg2`

Comment: To solve this in SourceTree 4.2.5, I initially switched to use the `system` git and not the `embedded` git since sourcetree was looking for `gpg2`. That didn't work. I switched back to use the `embedded` git and made a symlink as commented before: `n -s gpg gpg2`. That worked.

Answer (score 7):

Since SourceTree version 1.8.1, that checkbox will also be disabled if you had no GPG key when SourceTree was started. Creating your first GPG key while SourceTree is still running won't help. You will need to restart SourceTree in order for it to notice that you now have GPG keys.

Ref: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREE-1835

Comment: I have restarted but still the same

Comment: Thanks, this was my problem

Answer (score 1):

Although techpeace's answer seems to have resolved it for BJ Myers, there is also another possible reason for the option to remain greyed out despite correcting the setting.

If your keyring has been around for a while (close to 20 years in my case), chances are that some debris has piled up in one corner or another of the trust database. The tricky bit is that in most cases this doesn't show up in obvious ways, i.e. you can still sign, verify, encrypt, and decrypt stuff just fine. It's just that spurious `keyid_from_fingerprint: no pubkey` or `public key of ultimately trusted key 00000000 not found` that shows up from time to time (typically when using some keyring management front-end).

And this trustdb inconsistency was what prevented SourceTree from enabling the commit signing options in my case.

The solution is straightforward; simply follow [Spike's instructions for weeding out 00000000 keys from the trustdb](http://stuff-things.net/2015/04/22/gpg-public-key-of-ultimately-trusted-key-00000000-not-found/). Spike talks about one 00000000 entry, but in my case there were several. Just remove them all. Takes less than 5 minutes, and works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

### To set up Sourcetree to sign with GPG:

- Install gnupg: `brew install gnupg`

  - I found that gnupg was installed in `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gnupg/2.3.6/bin` (note `2.3.6` might be different for you, and /opt/homebrew is for ARM macs, brew installs to `/usr/local/bin` on intel macs)
- Ran `ln -s gpg gpg2` (as per a comment in another answer)
- Went into Sourcetree preferences (<kbd>Command + ,</kbd> > <kbd>Advanced</kbd> > <kbd>GPG Program</kbd>)

  - Pressed <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> and pasted the path from earlier: `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gnupg/2.3.6/bin`.

In SourceTree **mac menubar** > <kbd>Repository</kbd> > <kbd>Repository settings</kbd> > <kbd>Security</kbd> tab, enabled the checkbox: **enable GPG key signing for commits**